# Setup Windows on SSD doesn‘t work

Tags: windows, ssd, setup

I tried to change the HDD in my setup for an SSD (Samsung Evo 850 250GB) and wanted to install Windows 10 (latest release). However at the partitioning setup the SSD (now connected as only drive) shows up and I formated and partitioned the drive but instead of partitioning it for Windows (multiple partitions...) it just created one partition amd told me `Windows can‘t be installed on this device`.

I tried to reformat and to use diskpart to get the right format but it didn‘t work as well.

Comment: Can you give a little more details about your hardware configuration? Like motherboard, SSD type (SATA/PCIe/M.2) and more?

Comment: It is a SATA III SSD, my Motherboard is a Aszs M5A78L-M USB3. Processor is the AMD FX-6300. @iBug

Comment: Well I never ran into such a problem. Windows Installer always create the correct partition**s** on a clean disk and further more, I never install Windows using the canonical installer. I always partition and format by myself, then apply the WIM with `Dism.exe` and play the booting with `bcdboot.exe` (and Bootice).

Comment: Did you run a `chkdsk`? If yes, what was the result? You can access the console by pressing `shift` and `F10` during setup...

Comment: do you use BIOS/CSM or UEFI boot?

Comment: If you're partitioning yourself then please provide your partitions in your question and a screenshot of the error or the full error message. At first glance though you most likely didn't make an EFI system partition (ESP).

Answer (score 1):

If you're booting from a EFI BIOS, Windows demands an [EFI partition](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-8.1-and-8/hh825686(v=win.10)) to boot from.

You may get a Command Prompt by pressing Shift+F10 and they type:

```
diskpart

select disk 0
clean
convert gpt
create partition efi size=100
format quick fs=fat32 label="System"
assign letter="S"
create partition primary
format quick fs=ntfs label="Windows"
assign letter="W"
```

After this step, click in "Refresh" icon.
Everything should be good to go now.

Answer (score 0):

Don't partition the disk. Instead just select the unpartitioned disk and let Windows install to that. Windows will create the several partitions required automatically. If you manually create a partition, Windows won't be able to install because there won't be room to add the other required partitions.

Comment: i‘ve tried it, but it say that the Controller isn‘t right installed in the BIOS.

Comment: If I got the poster correctly he tried exactly that before. His problem is that Windows doesn‘t automatically format the disk right...

Comment: @creyD The way I read the post, he's trying to manually set up the partitions.

Comment: I tried both of it. @twisty impersonator

Comment: Please edit your question to clearly indicate you have tried installing Windows to the "Unpartitioned" space on the disk.